# string compatible enum-like structure

Tags: c++, enum, boost, macros

So I've decided to <strike>flex</strike> showcase my "enum that accepts strings etc..." here.

I don't know if it's great but I'm pretty sure it's decent. It is implemented in less than 200 lines of code (not counting `boost` helper macros), while something like [magic_enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum) is *thousands* of lines of code.

An enum-like structure is created from a macro call.

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <ostream>

/*  senum_t.h

    "string enum type".

    custom enum-like structure that accepts string construction/comparison/printing.

    usage (macro call):

        senum_t(NAME_OF_ENUM, IGNORE_CASE, ...ENUM_ENTRIES);
*/

namespace detail {

    std::string tolower(const char* str) {
        size_t slen = std::strlen(str);
        std::string lower(slen, '\0');
        for (size_t c = 0; c < slen; c++) {
            lower[c] = std::tolower(str[c]);
        }
        return lower;
    }
}

#define senum_t_STRINGIZE_CALLBACK(r, data, elem) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem),
#define senum_t_VA_ARGS_TO_STRINGS(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(senum_t_STRINGIZE_CALLBACK,, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))

#define senum_t(name, icase, ...) struct name {\
public:\
    typedef int value_type;\
    \
    enum enum_type : value_type {\
        __VA_ARGS__, BAD_STRING,\
    };\
private:\
    void _from_c_str(const char* sval) {/*nicase*/\
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s_ssval.size(); i++) {\
            if (std::strcmp(sval, s_ssval[i].c_str()) == 0) {\
                m_eval = static_cast<enum_type>(i);\
                return;\
            }\
        }\
        m_eval = enum_type::BAD_STRING;\
    }\
    void _from_c_str_i(const char* sval) {/*icase*/\
        std::string svall = detail::tolower(sval);\
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s_ssval.size(); i++) {\
            if (svall == detail::tolower(s_ssval[i].c_str())) {\
                m_eval = static_cast<enum_type>(i);\
                return;\
            }\
        }\
        m_eval = enum_type::BAD_STRING;\
    }\
private:\
    bool _is_equal_from_c_str(const char* sval) const {/*nicase*/\
        return std::strcmp(m_sval.c_str(), sval) == 0;\
    }\
    bool _is_equal_from_c_str_i(const char* sval) const {/*icase*/\
        return detail::tolower(m_sval.c_str()) == detail::tolower(sval);\
    }\
public:\
    name(const char* sval) : m_sval{ sval } {\
        s_icase ?\
            _from_c_str_i(sval) :\
            _from_c_str(sval);\
    }\
    name(const std::string& sval) : name(sval.c_str()) {\
    }\
    name(const enum_type eval) : m_eval{ eval } {\
        m_sval = s_ssval[static_cast<size_t>(eval)];\
    }\
    name() : name("") {\
    }\
public:\
    bool operator==(const name& other) const {\
        return m_eval == other.m_eval;\
    }\
    bool operator==(const enum_type eval) const {\
        return m_eval == eval;\
    }\
    bool operator==(const char* sval) const {\
        return s_icase ?\
            _is_equal_from_c_str_i(sval) :\
            _is_equal_from_c_str(sval);\
    }\
    bool operator==(const std::string& sval) const {\
        return s_icase ?\
            _is_equal_from_c_str_i(sval.c_str()) :\
            _is_equal_from_c_str(sval.c_str());\
    }\
public:\
    operator const enum_type& () const {\
        return m_eval;\
    }\
    operator const std::string& () const {\
        return m_sval;\
    }\
public:\
    static std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator sscbegin() {\
        return s_ssval.cbegin();\
    }\
    static std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator sscend() {\
        return s_ssval.cend();\
    }\
private:\
    enum_type\
        m_eval;\
    std::string\
        m_sval;\
    static const bool\
        s_icase;\
    static const std::vector<std::string>\
        s_ssval;\
    \
    friend bool operator==(const name::enum_type, const name&);\
    friend bool operator==(const char*, const name&);\
    friend bool operator==(const std::string&, const name&);\
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const name&);\
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const name::enum_type&);\
};\
/*static s_icase*/\
const bool name::s_icase = icase;\
/*static s_ssval*/\
const std::vector<std::string> name::s_ssval = {\
    senum_t_VA_ARGS_TO_STRINGS(__VA_ARGS__)\
    "BAD_STRING",\
};\
/*operator==(reverse order)*/\
bool operator==(const name::enum_type eval, const name& senum) {\
    return eval == senum.m_eval;\
}\
/*operator==(reverse order)*/\
bool operator==(const char* sval, const name& senum) {\
    return name::s_icase ?\
        detail::tolower(sval) == detail::tolower(senum.m_sval.c_str()) :\
        std::strcmp(sval, senum.m_sval.c_str()) == 0;\
}\
/*operator==(reverse order)*/\
bool operator==(const std::string& sval, const name& senum) {\
    return name::s_icase ?\
        detail::tolower(sval.c_str()) == detail::tolower(senum.m_sval.c_str()) :\
        sval == senum.m_sval;\
}\
/*printing*/\
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const name& senum) {\
    os << senum.m_sval;\
    return os;\
}\
/*bonus printing (with enum_type)*/\
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const name::enum_type& eval) {\
    os << name(eval).m_sval;\
    return os;\
}
```

Interactive demo: https://onlinegdb.com/mmEu7xZuK

Is the implementation lacking ?

Is the implementation going too far (looking at "out-of-class" friended `==` operators here) ?

Note: the current implementation doesn't accept non-default values for enum members. It could be implemenented with a `std::map` instead of `std::vector` for storing enum string names; a little more macro work is required for that.

Note: with help provided on macros here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77861361

UPDATE: I have noticed this design can produce duplicate symbols from different compilation units, so I've updated the code to use `inline` functions, and created a separate compilation unit for `detail::tolower`. The updated code can be found here https://onlinegdb.com/t77D7PDtxH

Answer (score 1):

## Reduce the reliance on macros

Your code does everything using macros, but I would try to use plain C++ as much as possible, and only rely on macros for the bits that can't be done in C++ itself. You can create templates of the functions and types you want to specialize for each enum you want to declare. For example:

```
namespace senum {
template<class Enum>
const std::vector<std::string> names;

template<class Enum>
const bool icase;
}

template<class Enum>
std::string to_string(Enum f) {
    return senum::names<Enum>[static_cast<std::size_t>(f)];
}

…

#define senum_t(name, icase, ...)\
enum name { __VA_ARGS__ };\
template<> const bool senum::icase<name> = icase;\
template<> const std::vector<std::string> senum::names<name> {\
    senum_t_VA_ARGS_TO_STRINGS(__VA_ARGS__)\
};
```

So `senum_t()` will now declare a *real* `enum`, and create a specialization of `senum::names<>` that will hold the names of all the enum values, and `senum::icase<>` will tell you if you should treat it case insensitive or not. Then add templated out-of-class function that will do string conversions and other operations as you like. Then the code using it looks like:

```
senum_t(DUMMY, false, hello, world, leet, other);

int main() {
    DUMMY dummy = hello;
    std::cout << to_string(dummy) << '\n';
}
```

Note that the above can be improved by using `static`/`inline`/`constexpr`, regular arrays with `const char*` strings to avoid the overhead of `std::vector` and `std::string`, and you might want to constrain `to_string()` so this definition only triggers for types that actually have a corresponding list of names. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

## Have a look at the Magic Enum library

With most compilers, you can in fact do static reflection on enums, without having to use macros to declare those enums. Have a look at the [Magic Enum library](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum). You could either use it directly, or look at its source code to draw inspiration.